# Why SFML 2.6 is making undefined reference errors but SFML 2.5.1 is not?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, game-development, sfml

I was trying to configure SFML 2.6 on Codeblocks for game development, but it was giving me lots of errors when building the project and the vast majority of errors was undefined reference (something like this "undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf6StringC1EPKcRKSt6locale'").

I tried lots of different solutions on the internet and different IDEs but none of them worked with me.
But the problem was solved when I tried an older version which is SFML 2.5.1 and everything worked very well (it also worked with SFML 2.3).

Was the problem because of bad setup or linking? or is it the library that has some bugs?

Here is the code that I used:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and this is the compiling commands:

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++", "-std=c++17", 
            "-I", "C:\\SFML\\include",
            "-L", "C:\\SFML\\lib", 
            "-o", "$file_base_name", "$file", "-lsfml-graphics", "-lsfml-window", "-lsfml-system"],
    "selector": "source.cpp",
    "working_dir": "$file_path",
    "shell": true
}
```

both of them was used for the old version and the new version of SFML.

Comment: Not very helpful but your example missing symbol is most likely about this https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/src/SFML/System/String.cpp#L70 . Maybe you have some conflicting version of headers and compiled libraries? Maybe you simply somehow corrupted the headers and now they don't match. Or you downloaded wrong version of the library and g++ cannot link with it.

Comment: In any case, you can try to just embed the source of SFML from github in your project and see i that will work - it should.

Comment: Maybe your sfml binaries are not compatible with MinGW or not compatible with your version of MinGW. I recommend if you use MinGW to install it via msys2 and install all your dependent opensource libraries using the built in package management `pacman` . This way you have the current MinGW and guaranteed compatible libraries.